# Aggregation query for populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to use MongoDB aggregation for populating `users` in `comments`. I can easily use it for populating `createdBy` with `$lookup` operator.

My question is there a way to maybe use `$each` operator in aggregation or something like that to populate `user` in comments?

I tried it with Mongo 3.2 but somewhere I read that it's going to be a new feature for something like that in 3.4?
I want to escape using a `$unwind` and `$groups` (I succeeded in doing that) and similar things so that the query doesn't become spaghetti code.

**users**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582c31d4afd9252c8515a88b"),
    "fullName": "test1"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("582c3db0afd9252c8515a88d"),
    "fullName": "test2"
}
```

and **posts**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5829cac7e9c0994d3db718f8"),
    "imgUrl": "images/test.jpg",
    "createdBy": ObjectId("582c31d4afd9252c8515a88b"),
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5829cab8e9c0994d3db718f7"),
            "content": "blabla",
            "user": ObjectId("582c31d4afd9252c8515a88b")
        }
    ]
}
```

**expected output**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5829cac7e9c0994d3db718f8"),
    "imgUrl": "images/test.jpg",
    "createdBy": ObjectId("582c31d4afd9252c8515a88b"),
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5829cab8e9c0994d3db718f7"),
            "content": "blabla",
            "user": {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("582c31d4afd9252c8515a88b"),
                        "fullName": "test1"
                    }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Styvane field `user` is like "FK" which I wanna override with all fields from `users` collection.

This is a result I want...
https://postimg.org/image/3n9bb9u0p/

Comment: Please you the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40736869/edit) on your question to add the expected output (document not image)

Comment: Is `comments` one element array?

Comment: @Styvane `comments` is array of many objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use **aggregation** function of **mongodb** then you can use below solution.

```
    db.getCollection('posts').aggregate([
    {"$unwind":{"path":"$comments","preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}},
    { $lookup:
            {
                from: 'users',
                localField: 'comments.user',
                foreignField:'_id',
                as: 'comments.user'
            }
    },
    {"$unwind":{"path":"$comments.user","preserveNullAndEmptyArrays":true}},
    {
            $group : {
                _id : "$_id",
                comments : {$push : "$comments"},
                imgUrl : {$first : "$imgUrl"},
                createdBy : {$first : "$createdBy"}
            }
    }

])
```

Make sure you have 3.2.8 or higher version of mongodb for using **$lookup** option

Answer (score 0):

Use populate method of mongoose.

```
db.collections.find({}).populate([{path:"comments.user"}]).
```

Comment: I want to do it with native mongo.